# Actionscript code not executed without user interaction

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

The following code works as expected: when a user clicks the button, the installer automatically launches.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="applicationInit(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.utils.setTimeout;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private var airSWF:Object;
        private var airSWFLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        private var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(); 

        private function applicationInit(event:FlexEvent):void {
            this.loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
            this.airSWFLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onAirInit);
            this.airSWFLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf"), loaderContext);
        }

        private function onAirInit(event:Event):void {
            this.airSWF = event.target.content;
            this.button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, installApp);
        }

        private function installApp(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var url:String = "URL HERE";
            var runtimeVersion:String = "2.7";
            var arguments:Array = ["launchFromBrowser"];
            this.airSWF.installApplication(url, runtimeVersion, arguments);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button id="button" label="Download" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
</s:Application>
```

Yet, suprisingly enough, the following code does not work as expected: it does not launch the installer upon creation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="applicationInit(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.utils.setTimeout;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private var airSWF:Object;
        private var airSWFLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        private var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(); 

        private function applicationInit(event:FlexEvent):void {
            this.loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
            this.airSWFLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onAirInit);
            this.airSWFLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf"), loaderContext);
        }

        private function onAirInit(event:Event):void {
            this.airSWF = event.target.content;
            installApp();
        }

        private function installApp():void {
            var url:String = "URL HERE";
            var runtimeVersion:String = "2.7";
            var arguments:Array = ["launchFromBrowser"];
            this.airSWF.installApplication(url, runtimeVersion, arguments);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button id="button" label="Download" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
</s:Application>
```

I verified that the installApp function is executed.

Why doesn't the second piece of code work? Is user interaction required? If so what's a way around this?

Comment: Without knowing the context within which you're trying to auto-install software I won't say **don't do it**, but installing software without the user's consent is both a major security risk and totally presumptuous.

Comment: Perhaps "installer" wasn't the right word. The above code opens a window asking the user if they would like to open or save the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, user interaction (user event) is needed for the AIR installer to work. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find official informations on this, but I've encountered this issue in the past. It's build that way for security reasons so that no app can install unwanted apps in the background.

EDIT :Found it : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html

> **Installing an AIR application from the browser**
>
> A SWF file can install an AIR application by calling the
>   installApplication() method in the air.swf file loaded from
>   http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf. For details, see
>   Loading the air.swf file.
>
> [...]
>
> The installApplication() method can only operate when called in the
>   event handler for a user event, such as a mouse click.
>
> The installApplication() method throws an error if the required
>   version of Flash Player (version 9 upgrade 3) is not installed in the
>   browser.

Comment: It is definitely a security thing - it's the same with trying to toggle into FullScreen, the user has to click something or it doesn't work.